# How to use dap-mode with TypeScript?

Tags: debugging, javascript, lsp

https://github.com/emacs-lsp/dap-mode provides DAP debugging for various languages (along the same lines as LSP does for completion, formatting, etc).

How can I use that to debug programs written in TypeScript (assuming that's possible currently)?

Comment: I haven't followed this yet but this looks like a great tutorial https://invidious.namazso.eu/watch?v=0bilcQVSlbM (https://youtube.com/watch?v=0bilcQVSlbM if you prefer)